# Stata type mismatch with local macro?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I'm trying to create a loop in Stata to run a bunch of regressions. This is a very simplified version of how it looks:

```
foreach y of local years{
    forval i=1/50 {
        local cov `: word `i' of `covariates''
        local int `: word `i' of `interactions''
        if `cov' != "N" {
            *regression stuff*
        }
    }
}
```

`years`, `covariates`, and `interactions` are local macros that I'm looping through, and the latter two have length 50. They each consist of strings, e.g.

```
local covariates "covariate1 covariate2 covariate3 covariate4"
```

The key thing here is that there are certain instances in `covariates` (and also `interactions` in the full code) where I have a string called "N", meaning I don't want to do the regression with the covariate in that instance. Hence, the

```
if `cov' != "N"
```

condition. The problem is that that line gives me a type mismatch error, and I'm not sure why. Would anyone know why this is the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here: `` if `cov' != "N" ``, `cov` evaluates to a variable name, and the first observation is compared with string "N", hence the type error.

You probably need:

```
if "`cov'" != "N"
```